# How to check whether the Mac OS X installation DVD I have is for my MacBook Pro?

Tags: snow-leopard, install

I just tried to reinstall OS X on my 13" MacBook Pro with the installation DVD that I have (OS is Snow Leopard, I bought around 2010). I followed all the reinstallation steps correctly, but what I got is a "Mac OS X cannot be installed on this computer" error. I read lots of forums post about the solutions and tried everything, but nothing works. I tried zeroing the partition several times with GUI partition scheme, did PRAM/NVRAM reset. Nothing works.

So there's only one scenario I need to check which is whether the Mac OS X installation DVD that I have is for my MacBook Pro. Can anyone please kindly point out to me how I can check whether the disc is the correct one for my MacBook Pro?

Comment: Can you please post a picture of your install discs?

Comment: posted on ur answer. pls check it

Comment: Unless you can specify which version of MacBook Pro you have - you'll have to look yours up on this handy chart: [Mac OS X versions (builds) for computers](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1159) Apple's phone support can also assist with determining if you have the correct discs (they can look up the printed numbers and help cross-reference) and as a bonus they can ship you replacements if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

It says so right on the disk.

[image: Image of OS X installation discs that came with a new Mac.]

Please don't pirate OS X.

Comment: how it says so on the disk ? Here is my disk picture http://i.imm.io/adIJ.jpeg . I don't pirate OS X. I am just confused whether i am using is my computer's cd or my brother's one.

Comment: See where it says 13-inch MacBook Pro Mac OS X Install DVD on the left? Also that disc is from 2011 (look at the copyright) so if you bought your MBP in 2010, unlikely yours. If you're confusing your media with your brother's why not just try the other set? I'm not seeing why this is such a problem?

Comment: yea, that's what I thought too when I saw copyright 2011. I can't test with other set because my brother lost that disc :/ Seems like I just need to call apple support and ask them to resend the disc

Comment: If it doesn't install, I think the answer is clear. Hopefully Apple can provide you with a solution. They might actually just give you a free copy of Lion instead. Call them.